# JavaScript - Append div based on attribute (multiple attributes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two containers which do not have any content. I would like to append content into these containers based on attributes other divs. My only trouble is, there are multiple values within the attribute, separated by a semi-colon which is breaking my existing code.

For example I have the following div:

```
<div class="item-container" location="United States; United Kingdom"></div>
```

My JavaScript currently looks like this:

```
$('.item-container').each(function () {
   var location = $(this).attr('location');
   if (location == "United States") { $('#american-container').append(location );}
});
```

Now, this works perfectly fine in the instance where the location attribute contains "United States" alone. However, when there are multiple values in the "Location" attribute, this breaks.

Is there a way to ensure my "if" statement can work well even when other values are present?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `location` is not a valid attribute, you should use instead: `data-location` and retrieve its value using `.data('location')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `indexOf()`

```
 if (location.indexOf("United States") >-1)
```

If your code looks like this

```
$('.item-container').each(function () {
   var location = $(this).attr('location');
   if (location.indexOf("United States") >-1) { $('#american-container').append(location );}
  if (location.indexOf("United kingdom") >-1) { $('#europe-container').append(location );}
});
```

Then you already know what you are looking for then you could change location to the if string like this

```
   if (location.indexOf("United States") >-1) {$('#american-container').append("United States");}
    if (location.indexOf("United kingdom") >-1) {$('#europe-container').append("United kingdom");}
```

Comment: Hi Anton - Thank you for the rapid response. Are you suggesting the following? if (location.indexOf("United States") > -1) { $('#american-container').append(location); } - If so, this carries the united states value and other values too (such as united kingdom)

Comment: Ah, thought you wanted all of it with, i'll work on something i'll update my answer soon

Comment: @Tron If you already know what you are going to append why not just append('United States') ?

Comment: I don't know what I'm going to append. I'm using a Content Management System. The "Location" attribute automatically pulls through items entered into a list. What I'm trying to do, is say, if the value that happens to come through is "United States", grab it and push it into another container. So it's a big IF. United States might not come through, but I need to cater for the potential chance that it will.